# How to remap <C> (control) modifier key in vim?

Tags: vim, mappings, modifier-key

I avoid the "control" key, AKA `<C>` in vim parlance, on my laptop; I hate where Apple put it. I would really like to remap all of the vim commands using control to instead use "command", but this does not seem possible on a Mac, despite what I have read. I have read that I should use `<Leader>` to set such mappings, but I want to avoid remapping every single `<C>` mapping that I can find or think of in my .vimrc, just to forget some and bloat my .vimrc.

I want to avoid xmodmap or solutions beyond the scope of .vimrc, as I want to maintain compatibility of my config files that I sync across systems.

What I really want to do is specify an alternate key (probably `,`) as a modifier key equivalent to `<C>`.

Comment: what about remapping your keyboard? I for one remap ctrl on all my keyboards to the caps lock key. Makes it way easier..

Comment: I am aware that this is a common solution, but as I stated, I want to avoid solutions that go beyond the scope of .vimrc if I can.

Comment: Oh my, I feel your pain.

Comment: Ctrl sucks on the macbooks.  I've been dealing with it, but one huge help for me was remapping CapsLock to "help" and then *map <Help> <Esc>.  I figure you gotta hit escape even more than ctrl, so might as well make it easy to access!

Comment: you might be out of luck. vim doesn't get a `ctrl` and then a `v` from the os, it just gets a `C-v` all at once, vim doesn't handle the ctrl keystrokes itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is definitely no vim-only solution for this; vim simply does not have this capability. Map `<CapsLock>` to `<Ctrl>` in `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys...`, take a few minutes to adjust, and repeat for every MacBook you ever lay hands on (even if it's not yours). The world will be a better place for it.

Comment: I'm very reluctantly accepting this answer. After 594 views over the past year and no solutions proposed, I suppose that vim is for once incapable of such a task.

Comment: @iconoclast, Why did you bother adding to this discussion about a text editor you seem to despise?

Comment: How about exchanging the roles of Control and Option instead of remapping Caps Lock? Plays well with tmux and also makes it easy to type EOF.

Comment: i am remapping it for the first macbook out of all future macbooks now